# Java ee 7 wildfly database/form authentication

Tags: jakarta-ee, forms-authentication, wildfly

I try to create simple form based authentication with database(user/roles on Postgresql 9.3) on wildfly 8.2. 
my standalone.xml

```
  <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/Test"/>
                        <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="Select password from myuser where name=?"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role,'Roles' from user_roles wher name=?"/>
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```

I try code="database" but didn't work so i changed it on what u see above. i also add logger in

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">
<logger category="org.jboss.security">
                <level name="TRACE"/>
            </logger>
```

i registered domain in webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml and it's default so it shouldn't be a problem

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>other</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

my web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>admin</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/addBook.html</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>other</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
</security-role>
```

my form in login.html

```
<form action="j_security_check" method=post>
<strong>Please Enter Your User Name: </strong></br>
<input type="text" name="j_username"></br>
<strong>Please Enter Your Password: </strong></br>
<input type="password" name="j_password"></br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Login!">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

At end my 2 enties

```
 @Entity(name="Myuser")
public class MyUser {
    @Id 
    @NotNull
    @Column(name="name", unique=true)
    private String userName;
    @NotNull
    private String password;
    @NotNull
    private String email;
//... getters etc.

@Table(name="USER_ROLES")
@Entity(name="UserRoles")
public class UserRoles {
@NotNull
@Column(name="role")
String groupName;
@NotNull
@Id
@Column(name="name", unique=true)
String userName;
//...getters etc.
```

After clicked Login!, it move me to error.html and nothing happens. Logger don't give me any clues, 0 response. Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: i solved it. I change 
         <logger category="org.jboss.security">
        <level name="TRACE"/>
          <handlers>
              <handler name="AUDIT"/>
         </handlers>
     </logger>
Then i change sql query thx logs and gj.

Comment: <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="AUDIT" autoflush="true">
          <level name="TRACE"/>
          <formatter>
              <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
          </formatter>
          <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="audit.log"/>
          <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
          <append value="true"/>
         </periodic-rotating-file-handler>

Comment: <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required"><module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/Test"/><module-option name="principalsQuery" value="Select PASSWORD from MYUSER where name=?"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role,'Roles' from user_roles where name=?"/>                          <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
          <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
                        </login-module>